# Convert a String to HashMap

Tags: java, json, string, dictionary

I am getting this string from a service. I want a map or json out of this. It should look like this.

```
Map output
  Total time taken:226006
  nodea:10615
  nodez:5308'


String timingTrace = "Total time taken:226006.,"
            + "time spent in nodes:{\"nodea\":{\"timeTaken\":10615},\"nodez\":{\"timeTaken\":5308}}\"";
```

What I have tried so for is the below code. Can I do something better? Any library that can easily convert the above string to map.

```
if (timingTrace != null) {
        arrayofTimeStamp = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(StringUtils.remove(timingTrace, " "), ".,");
    }
String[] totaltime = StringUtils.split(arrayofTimeStamp[0], ":")

Map<String,Object> timestamps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
timestamp.put(totaltime[0], totaltime[1]);

String[] nodetimestamp = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(arrayofTimeStamp[1], "time spent in nodes:");

getMapped(nodetimestamp[1]);

public void getMapped(String json) throws JSONException, ParseException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        String timetaken = JsonPath.read(json, "$." + key + ".timeTaken");
        timestamp.put(key, timetaken);
   }
}
```

Comment: There is some compile error in your code. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `timestamp` Map<> object in function `getMapped(String json)` that give you error because you haven't passed it you declare in function.

To get output you have mention change write below code instead of function `getMapped(String json)` :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(nodetimestamp[1]);
Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) 
{
    String key = keys.next();
    String timetakenStr = obj.getString(key);
    JSONObject child = new JSONObject(timetakenStr);
    timestamps.put(key, child.getString("timeTaken"));
}
```

Using above code your `Map<>` will contain same what you mention. 
OutPut :

```
{nodea=10615, Total time taken=226006, nodez=5308}
```